# Autocomplete Textview shows wrong suggestions in Android

Tags: android, json, android-layout, filter, autocomplete

`AutocompleteTextview` display results in dropdown but does not show relevant suggestions. This textview displays all values in dropdown onClick. i want to apply filter on `autocompleteTextview's` data. I don't want to change AsyncTask. i want to apply filter on `arrayadapter` values which are stored in autocomplete textview.

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<EnglishTranslatorModel> data) {


            final AutoCompleteAdapter adapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.translation,data);


            autoCompleteTextView1.setAdapter(adapter);


            super.onPostExecute(data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you share your AutoCompleteAdapter

Comment: i already answered what you should do, twice, and this is your 6th question regarding your issue (not counting deleted questions), why dont you follow that simple answer (just 20 lines of code) ?

Comment: I can't use your given solution because i am fetching data from json and want to perform another task on fetched data

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren check my complete code here for error [Complete Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535613/filter-is-not-working-drop-down-values-are-irrelevent-android)

Comment: link is not found, just add it in your question,